# Remove bootstrap accordion panel (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I have a bootstrap accordion whose panels are generated according the input in an `input type=number`. The problem is that when I want to delete, it removes a panel. I have only been able to remove the internal div, but the `panel-heading` still appears in the accordion.

This is the HTML for accordion:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

    </div>
</div>
```

and the template:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="template_shovel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
                    Shovel 01
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
Some more HTML
</div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var hash = 1;
$(function () {
    $(':input').bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
        var $templateShovel = $('#template_shovel');

        if (this.id == 'nshovels') {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == hash) {
                var $newPanel = $templateShovel.clone();
                $newPanel.find(".collapse").removeClass("in");
                $newPanel.find(".accordion-toggle").attr("href", "#collapseShovel" + (hash))
                         .text("Shovel - n #" + hash);
                $newPanel.find(".panel-collapse").attr("id", "collapseShovel" + hash).addClass("collapse").removeClass("in");
                $('#accordion').append($newPanel.fadeIn());
                hash++;
            }
            else if (value < hash) {
                var idPanel = '#collapseShovel' + (hash - 1).toString();
                $('#accordion').find(idPanel).closest('div').andSelf().remove();

                hash--;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

`nshovels` is the input's id that has to add or delete panels.

Comment: I think you have an exrea `</div>` there in the template

Comment: @Vemonus you are right. Edited!

Comment: and thanks for the suggested edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you are trying to delete both the `div.panel-heading` AND `div.panel-collapse`, but keep the `div.panel`. To this can use `.empty()` after targeting the panel. This will remove all child elements, but keep the `div.panel` itself.

```
var idPanel = '#collapseShovel' + (hash - 1).toString();
$('#accordion').find(idPanel).closest('.panel').empty();
```

Otherwise if you're trying to remove the actual `div.panel` item that contains the `div.panel-heading` and `div.panel-collapse`:

```
var idPanel = '#collapseShovel' + (hash - 1).toString();
$('#accordion').find(idPanel).closest('.panel').remove();
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q4uag36k/5/) demonstrating the basic `remove()` vs `empty()` functionality for an collapse panel accordion as well as `input:number` blur example:

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was only that I was removing the closest div instead of the panel. I feel a little silly now.